# How to set background-color of icon and when hover on li background color also get same color with icon background color using css

Tags: css

I want to set background-color of icon grey color and whenever i hover on li background-color of "li"
also get grey color but the CSS which i have defined it is not working how to do that ?

```css
.main-menu li .fa-home,
.main-menu li.apps1:hover {
  background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<ul class="main-menu">
  <li class="apps1">
    <a href="#">
      <span class="fa fa-home"></span>
      <span class="text">Dashboard</span>
    </a>

  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Your question isn't very clear. Can you please clarify?

Comment: @AdamChubbuck i want background-color of icon fa-home is gery ,and at the same time when mouseover or hover on that li complete background-color also get gery, but that css is not working

Comment: Please view my answer and let me know if that is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below will apply the grey background to the `li` element when it is hovered. Since the icon is a child of this element, it will appear to have a grey background as well.

```css
.main-menu li:hover {
  background-color: grey;
}

.main-menu li a .fa {
  color: grey;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<ul class="main-menu">
  <li class="apps1">
    <a href="#">
      <span class="fa fa-home"></span>
      <span class="text">Dashboard</span>
    </a>

  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: @adma chubbuck but normally the  background-color of icon should be gery not blue and hover also get grey color

Comment: The icon is blue because it is wrapped inside of an `a` tag. I've updated my answer to target that rule and revert the `color` attribute for the element to grey.